# Unable to link the grpc libraries in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, grpc, vcpkg

I have installed grpc:x64 using vcpkg in windows and I am trying to compile the basic greeter server program. But it is giving me linking errors. Even though the find_package command is able to find the grpc package, I suspect that the library paths are not set properly. I am not able to figure out the exact reason for this issue. If find_package is successful, do I have to provide the library paths explicitly?

OS: Windows 10
Tool chain: Visual Studio 15

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.1 )

project( test )

find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)

find_package( Protobuf REQUIRED )

add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp proto/hello_world.grpc.pb.cc  proto/hello_world.pb.cc)

target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE gRPC::grpc++ gRPC::gpr gRPC::grpc gRPC::grpc++ gRPC::grpc_cronet protobuf::libprotoc protobuf::libprotobuf protobuf::libprotobuf-lite )
```

I am getting the following errors while the basic greeting server program

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Release x64 ------

    1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl grpc_impl::reflection::InitProtoReflectionServerBuilderPlugin(void)" (?InitProtoReflectionServerBuilderPlugin@reflection@grpc_impl@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl RunServer(void)" (?RunServer@@YAXXZ)
    1>C:\all_files\junkyard\_grpc\build\Release\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    2>------ Skipped Build: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Release x64 ------
    2>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

Any pointers in identifying the issue will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Please add your errors messages in **full**, and as *text*, not as images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured out the missing library. `gRPC::grpc++_reflection` needs to be added in the dependency list.

Comment: How did you figure this out? Are there any helpful commands?